# Recompute transformation in Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm using a ListView to display different transformations on the same image using Picasso. Basically I made a custom transformation that returns a subset (rectangle) of an image.

```
Picasso
        .with(context)
        .load(url)
        .transform(new CropTransformation(...));
```

However with Picasso's caching, it also caches the transformation instead of recomputing the transformation. I would like it to cache the image but not the transformed bitmap. What would be the preferred way of achieving that?

Bonus question: Is there a way to make it cache the transformed bitmap only when the parameters to the custom transformation matches?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by serializing the parameters of the transformation constructor and setting it as the key.

```
@Override
public String key() {
    return "my_transformation-" + serializedParameters;
}
```